# Laravel 5 trying to write on /UniqueIDPath

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

Hi I'm facing a very frustrating problem, my laravel instance is showing this error.

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 74:
file_put_contents(/43dc150b6c864d7c0166002994bb8cbc): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

the storage directory is writable and app,framework, logs directory is also created in that folder, I've also change the permission of storage to 775 but still such error appear. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the user running your http server inside the group of the owner of the storage directory? Because otherwise it just falls into "all users", and the '5' of '775' prevents him from writing.

Comment: That doesn't answers the question. Try changing (temporarily) your storage (and subdirectories) to '777' to double check it is not a privilege problem.

Comment: But you said you managed to change the permission of storage to 775... then you can change it to 777.

Comment: Can you find out where is the directory it is trying to create that file? Can't you show the full stack error?

Comment: Make a `<?php echo sys_get_temp_dir();?>` . That's (probably) the directory where Laravel is trying to create temporary files. Make sure it has privileges to create files there.

Comment: What about <?php echo storage_path();?>

Comment: Ok, let me see... edit `/config/view.php`and add/change the line defining 'compiled' with this:      'compiled' => realpath('storage/framework/views'),

Comment: @Amarnasan yes the path is correct, / its show /home/default/storage, now I'm thinking ngnix don't have rights to create files